# Force dynamic linker to load library at runtime in Linux

Tags: linux, ld, dlopen

So a little bit of history, I have 3 libs:

- "lib1.so" with no dependencies
- "lib2.so" which is linked with "lib1.so"
- "test" executable program with no dependencies

What I need is to dynamically load "lib2.so" during runtime from "test" executable via "dlopen" method. The problem is that "lib1.so" cannot be loaded automatically due to linker doesn't know where to find it.

I've tried to load "lib1.so" at first like that:

```
void* ptr_lib1 = dlopen("/usr/local/test/lib1.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
void* ptr_lib2 = dlopen("/usr/local/test/lib2.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

But that's not working by some reason, it gives me error after calling second dlopen (text from dlerror):

```
"lib1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

It means that "lib1.so" is trying to be loaded twice: first time when I call dlopen for "lib1.so", and second when I call dlopen for "lib2.so".

Can anyone explain why and what to do to fix that? Please, don't advise to modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH before starting executable. Also don't advise to modify linker flags of executable. I need to be able load that libs at runtime from any folder.

**UPDATE.** 
After some research I did this:

```
LD_DEBUG=all ./test
```

And found that library lib1.so is trying to be loaded twice (first when I call dlopen, second when LD trying to resolve dependency for lib2.so"):

```
add /usr/local/test/lib1.so [0] to global scope
opening file=/usr/local/test/lib1.so [0]; direct_opencount=1
...
    30031:  file=lib1.so [0];  needed by /usr/local/test/lib2.so [0]
 30031: find library=lib1.so [0]; searching
 30031:  search path=./tls/x86_64:./tls:./x86_64:.      (RPATH from file ./test)
 30031:   trying file=./tls/x86_64/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=./tls/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=./x86_64/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=./lib1.so
 30031:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 30031:  search path=/lib64/tls/x86_64:/lib64/tls:/lib64/x86_64:/lib64:/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64/x86_64:/usr/lib64        (system search path)
 30031:   trying file=/lib64/tls/x86_64/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=/lib64/tls/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=/lib64/x86_64/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=/lib64/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=/usr/lib64/x86_64/lib1.so
 30031:   trying file=/usr/lib64/lib1.so
 30031:
 30031:
 30031: file=/usr/local/test/lib2.so [0];  destroying link map
```

Still don't understand what is going on...

**UPDATE2.** There is full [LD_DEBUG log](https://nofile.io/f/jMGVSVHVGe4/debug.txt)

Note: there is another library lib_other.so, just ignore it

Comment: "that's not working" - what happens when you try?  Are lib1 and lib2 always in the same directory as each other?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I've updated question

Comment: Can you run with `LD_DEBUG=all`?

Comment: @yugr see update, lib2.so loaded twice. How is that?

Comment: @AlekDepler Please add log for first load of `lib1.so` (after `opening file=/usr/local/test/lib1.so [0]`). We need to understand why linker failed to load it from `/usr/local/test`, that's the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @yugr see update2

Comment: I think that lib2.so has a `NEEDED lib1.so` in its header. It does not matter that you loaded some `lib1.so` manually, it still needs to load a `lib1.so` by itself. And since `lib1.so` is not in the default seach path, you get a dl error.

Answer (score 1):

When [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) fails, you should use [dlerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlerror.3.html) to get some useful message.

So code at least:

```
void* ptr_lib1 
   = dlopen("/usr/local/test/lib1.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (!ptr_lib1) {
   fprintf(stderr, "dlopen lib1 failure: %s\n", dlerror());
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and likewise for other `dlopen`s

Notice that `dlerror` is giving a *detailed* error message. If you don't understand it, put it in your question.

You probably forgot to set some [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) when linking `lib1.so` or `lib2.so`. Or you need to set explicitly `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or run `ldconfig`

Read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper for details. Read carefully [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html)

`dlopen` of `lib2` fails because its dependency `lib1` is not found. You need to fix that (thru rpath, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `ldconfig` etc...)

You could add some `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/test/lib1.so` in `lib1` options, etc

You could also (more simply) decide that all your shared libraries go into `/usr/local/lib/` which you would mention in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. Then you need to run `ldconfig` after every library addition there.

Comment: I dont want to use rpath or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I need the way to load that libraries from any folder without restrictions and environment variables

Comment: You probably cannot do that (but I am not sure to understand what you really want to do; I guess you don't understand shared libraries well enough; reading Drepper's paper should help).

Comment: "you should use dlerror(3) to get some useful message" - isn't that the "No such file or directory" message?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem seems to be that `lib1.so` is `NEEDED` by `lib2.so`, which happens because you linked it at build time.  So simply don't link it at build time--don't mention `lib1` at all when building `lib2`.  Then you can load it with `dlopen()` as you wish, and `lib2` won't try to load it independently.

Comment: The root of this problem is Linux architecture, there is no such problems in Windows even if library linked

Comment: @AlekDepler: You're right.  You should consider using Windows instead if you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, but it just works. I just use with "RTLD_LAZY" instead of "RTLD_NOW".

You can try it.