# Debug postmortem a dlopen() handle?

Tags: linux, gdb, dlopen

I have a corefile and want to debug a handle returned by `dlopen()` e.g. verify that is is still intact. `dlsym()` function invoked on a handle indicates `this=0x0` in the stack-trace. Is there a description of what's behind a `dlopen()` handle? Or do i have to check the `libdl.so` source code?

Comment: Show some [MCVE]. AFAIK, the `core` file contains some traces about that `dlopen` -it knows what files has been `mmap`-ed-

Comment: `this=0x0` often means a static object is not yet initialized. It is hard to say if that is the problem without knowing more about your code. Also see [C++ FAQ | Static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors).

Answer (score 2):

`Dlopen` returns `NULL` if it failed to locate or load library (in which case there's nothing else you need to debug) or pointer to `link_map` data structure which defined in public Glibc header `link.h` (see [this](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/master/include/link.h) for example).

Answer (score 1):

[dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) can fail, and gives `NULL` in that case. And you should *always* test against such a failure (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49490647/841108)). I guess that some `dlopen` failed in your case but you forgot to test it (that could explain your `this=0` reported by `gdb` in `dlsym`). However, on Linux, you could do many hundreds of thousands of successful `dlopen`-s,  see my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) example. Of course you should not use [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) with a `NULL` shared object handle (otherwise it is [undefined bahavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), with a probable [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)).

To find, on Linux specifically, given some address to which function it might belong, you could use [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html).

Notice that [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) files know about the `mmap`-ed memory segments (unless perhaps they are incomplete, because you reached some limit set with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) using `RLIMIT_CORE`)

See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). If you can reproduce your bug into some process 1234, look into `/proc/1234/maps` while that process is still active.

> Is there a description somewhere what's behind a dlopen() handle?

It is some [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) (to be used only with `dlopen`, `dlsym`, `dlclose` and [dlinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlinfo.3.html)... see also [dl_iterate_phdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html).), so portable programs don't need to care. Of course, you might study the implementation of `dlopen`  e.g. inside source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). See also your system's `/usr/include/link.h` and its `struct link_map` (thanks to [yugr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2170527/yugr) comment)